# Ruby on Rails-Login page with sign up

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Im a beginner in rails. trying to create an user sign up and sign in. i have just created front page. Is ter any option to authenticate user and add new user to db without using any gem???

Answer (score 0):

You can add
 `before_action :authenticate`

at the top of your controller .rb file  and add an authenticate method that adds the user to the database:

```
def authenticate
  #do your stuff here.
end
```